# Detecting Java version (runnable in browser) with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, deployment, java, version-detection

I was checking [this code](http://java.com/js/deployJava.js) provided by Sun that can retrieve a list of the *Java Runtime Environments* installed on the machine. Here's the code formatted and with some functions removed so it's easier to read:

```
var deployJava = {
    debug: null,
    firefoxJavaVersion: null,
    returnPage: null,
    locale: null,
    oldMimeType: 'application/npruntime-scriptable-plugin;DeploymentToolkit',
    mimeType: 'application/java-deployment-toolkit',
    browserName: null,
    browserName2: null,
    getJREs: function () {
        var list = new Array();
        if (deployJava.isPluginInstalled()) {
            var plugin = deployJava.getPlugin();
            var VMs = plugin.jvms;
            for (var i = 0; i < VMs.getLength(); i++) {
                list[i] = VMs.get(i).version;
            }
        } else {
            var browser = deployJava.getBrowser();
            if (browser == 'MSIE') {
                if (deployJava.testUsingActiveX('1.7.0')) {
                    list[0] = '1.7.0';
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingActiveX('1.6.0')) {
                    list[0] = '1.6.0';
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingActiveX('1.5.0')) {
                    list[0] = '1.5.0';
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingActiveX('1.4.2')) {
                    list[0] = '1.4.2';
                } else if (deployJava.testForMSVM()) {
                    list[0] = '1.1';
                }
            } else if (browser == 'Netscape Family') {
                deployJava.getJPIVersionUsingMimeType();
                if (deployJava.firefoxJavaVersion != null) {
                    list[0] = deployJava.firefoxJavaVersion;
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingMimeTypes('1.7')) {
                    list[0] = '1.7.0';
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingMimeTypes('1.6')) {
                    list[0] = '1.6.0';
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingMimeTypes('1.5')) {
                    list[0] = '1.5.0';
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingMimeTypes('1.4.2')) {
                    list[0] = '1.4.2';
                } else if (deployJava.browserName2 == 'Safari') {
                    if (deployJava.testUsingPluginsArray('1.7.0')) {
                        list[0] = '1.7.0';
                    } else if (deployJava.testUsingPluginsArray('1.6')) {
                        list[0] = '1.6.0';
                    } else if (deployJava.testUsingPluginsArray('1.5')) {
                        list[0] = '1.5.0';
                    } else if (deployJava.testUsingPluginsArray('1.4.2')) {
                        list[0] = '1.4.2';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (deployJava.debug) {
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                alert('We claim to have detected Java SE ' + list[i]);
            }
        }
        return list;
    },
    runApplet: function (attributes, parameters, minimumVersion) {
        if (minimumVersion == 'undefined' || minimumVersion == null) {
            minimumVersion = '1.1';
        }
        var regex = "^(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:_(\\d+))?)?)?$";
        var matchData = minimumVersion.match(regex);
        if (deployJava.returnPage == null) {
            deployJava.returnPage = document.location;
        }
        if (matchData != null) {
            var browser = deployJava.getBrowser();
            if ((browser != '?') && ('Safari' != deployJava.browserName2)) {
                if (deployJava.versionCheck(minimumVersion + '+')) {
                    deployJava.writeAppletTag(attributes, parameters);
                }
            } else {
                deployJava.writeAppletTag(attributes, parameters);
            }
        } else {
            if (deployJava.debug) {
                alert('Invalid minimumVersion argument to runApplet():' + minimumVersion);
            }
        }
    },
    writeAppletTag: function (attributes, parameters) {
        var startApplet = '<' + 'applet ';
        var params = '';
        var endApplet = '<' + '/' + 'applet' + '>';
        var addCodeAttribute = true;
        for (var attribute in attributes) {
            startApplet += (' ' + attribute + '="' + attributes[attribute] + '"');
            if (attribute == 'code' || attribute == 'java_code') {
                addCodeAttribute = false;
            }
        }
        if (parameters != 'undefined' && parameters != null) {
            var codebaseParam = false;
            for (var parameter in parameters) {
                if (parameter == 'codebase_lookup') {
                    codebaseParam = true;
                }
                if (parameter == 'object' || parameter == 'java_object') {
                    addCodeAttribute = false;
                }
                params += '<param name="' + parameter + '" value="' + parameters[parameter] + '"/>';
            }
            if (!codebaseParam) {
                params += '<param name="codebase_lookup" value="false"/>';
            }
        }
        if (addCodeAttribute) {
            startApplet += (' code="dummy"');
        }
        startApplet += '>';
        document.write(startApplet + '\n' + params + '\n' + endApplet);
    },
    versionCheck: function (versionPattern) {
        var index = 0;
        var regex = "^(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:_(\\d+))?)?)?(\\*|\\+)?$";
        var matchData = versionPattern.match(regex);
        if (matchData != null) {
            var familyMatch = true;
            var patternArray = new Array();
            for (var i = 1; i < matchData.length; ++i) {
                if ((typeof matchData[i] == 'string') && (matchData[i] != '')) {
                    patternArray[index] = matchData[i];
                    index++;
                }
            }
            if (patternArray[patternArray.length - 1] == '+') {
                familyMatch = false;
                patternArray.length--;
            } else {
                if (patternArray[patternArray.length - 1] == '*') {
                    patternArray.length--;
                }
            }
            var list = deployJava.getJREs();
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                if (deployJava.compareVersionToPattern(list[i], patternArray, familyMatch)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('Invalid versionPattern passed to versionCheck: ' + versionPattern);
            return false;
        }
    },
    isWebStartInstalled: function (minimumVersion) {
        var browser = deployJava.getBrowser();
        if ((browser == '?') || ('Safari' == deployJava.browserName2)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (minimumVersion == 'undefined' || minimumVersion == null) {
            minimumVersion = '1.4.2';
        }
        var retval = false;
        var regex = "^(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:_(\\d+))?)?)?$";
        var matchData = minimumVersion.match(regex);
        if (matchData != null) {
            retval = deployJava.versionCheck(minimumVersion + '+');
        } else {
            if (deployJava.debug) {
                alert('Invalid minimumVersion argument to isWebStartInstalled(): ' + minimumVersion);
            }
            retval = deployJava.versionCheck('1.4.2+');
        }
        return retval;
    },
    getJPIVersionUsingMimeType: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < navigator.mimeTypes.length; ++i) {
            var s = navigator.mimeTypes[i].type;
            var m = s.match(/^application\/x-java-applet;jpi-version=(.*)$/);
            if (m != null) {
                deployJava.firefoxJavaVersion = m[1];
                if ('Opera' != deployJava.browserName2) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    isPluginInstalled: function () {
        var plugin = deployJava.getPlugin();
        if (plugin && plugin.jvms) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    isPlugin2: function () {
        if (deployJava.isPluginInstalled()) {
            if (deployJava.versionCheck('1.6.0_10+')) {
                try {
                    return deployJava.getPlugin().isPlugin2();
                } catch (err) {}
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
    allowPlugin: function () {
        deployJava.getBrowser();
        var ret = ('Safari' != deployJava.browserName2 && 'Opera' != deployJava.browserName2);
        return ret;
    },
    getPlugin: function () {
        deployJava.refresh();
        var ret = null;
        if (deployJava.allowPlugin()) {
            ret = document.getElementById('deployJavaPlugin');
        }
        return ret;
    },
    compareVersionToPattern: function (version, patternArray, familyMatch) {
        var regex = "^(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:_(\\d+))?)?)?$";
        var matchData = version.match(regex);
        if (matchData != null) {
            var index = 0;
            var result = new Array();
            for (var i = 1; i < matchData.length; ++i) {
                if ((typeof matchData[i] == 'string') && (matchData[i] != '')) {
                    result[index] = matchData[i];
                    index++;
                }
            }
            var l = Math.min(result.length, patternArray.length);
            if (familyMatch) {
                for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
                    if (result[i] != patternArray[i]) return false;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
                    if (result[i] < patternArray[i]) {
                        return false;
                    } else if (result[i] > patternArray[i]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    getBrowser: function () {
        if (deployJava.browserName == null) {
            var browser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            if (deployJava.debug) {
                alert('userAgent -> ' + browser);
            }
            if (browser.indexOf('msie') != -1) {
                deployJava.browserName = 'MSIE';
                deployJava.browserName2 = 'MSIE';
            } else if (browser.indexOf('iphone') != -1) {
                deployJava.browserName = 'Netscape Family';
                deployJava.browserName2 = 'iPhone';
            } else if (browser.indexOf('firefox') != -1) {
                deployJava.browserName = 'Netscape Family';
                deployJava.browserName2 = 'Firefox';
            } else if (browser.indexOf('chrome') != -1) {
                deployJava.browserName = 'Netscape Family';
                deployJava.browserName2 = 'Chrome';
            } else if (browser.indexOf('safari') != -1) {
                deployJava.browserName = 'Netscape Family';
                deployJava.browserName2 = 'Safari';
            } else if (browser.indexOf('mozilla') != -1) {
                deployJava.browserName = 'Netscape Family';
                deployJava.browserName2 = 'Other';
            } else if (browser.indexOf('opera') != -1) {
                deployJava.browserName = 'Netscape Family';
                deployJava.browserName2 = 'Opera';
            } else {
                deployJava.browserName = '?';
                deployJava.browserName2 = 'unknown';
            }
            if (deployJava.debug) {
                alert('Detected browser name:' + deployJava.browserName + ', ' + deployJava.browserName2);
            }
        }
        return deployJava.browserName;
    },
    testUsingActiveX: function (version) {
        var objectName = 'JavaWebStart.isInstalled.' + version + '.0';
        if (!ActiveXObject) {
            if (deployJava.debug) {
                alert('Browser claims to be IE, but no ActiveXObject object?');
            }
            return false;
        }
        try {
            return (new ActiveXObject(objectName) != null);
        } catch (exception) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    testForMSVM: function () {
        var clsid = '{08B0E5C0-4FCB-11CF-AAA5-00401C608500}';
        if (typeof oClientCaps != 'undefined') {
            var v = oClientCaps.getComponentVersion(clsid, "ComponentID");
            if ((v == '') || (v == '5,0,5000,0')) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    testUsingMimeTypes: function (version) {
        if (!navigator.mimeTypes) {
            if (deployJava.debug) {
                alert('Browser claims to be Netscape family, but no mimeTypes[] array?');
            }
            return false;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < navigator.mimeTypes.length; ++i) {
            s = navigator.mimeTypes[i].type;
            var m = s.match(/^application\/x-java-applet\x3Bversion=(1\.8|1\.7|1\.6|1\.5|1\.4\.2)$/);
            if (m != null) {
                if (deployJava.compareVersions(m[1], version)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
    testUsingPluginsArray: function (version) {
        if ((!navigator.plugins) || (!navigator.plugins.length)) {
            return false;
        }
        var platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; ++i) {
            s = navigator.plugins[i].description;
            if (s.search(/^Java Switchable Plug-in (Cocoa)/) != -1) {
                if (deployJava.compareVersions("1.5.0", version)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (s.search(/^Java/) != -1) {
                if (platform.indexOf('win') != -1) {
                    if (deployJava.compareVersions("1.5.0", version) || deployJava.compareVersions("1.6.0", version)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (deployJava.compareVersions("1.5.0", version)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    compareVersions: function (installed, required) {
        var a = installed.split('.');
        var b = required.split('.');
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            a[i] = Number(a[i]);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
            b[i] = Number(b[i]);
        }
        if (a.length == 2) {
            a[2] = 0;
        }
        if (a[0] > b[0]) return true;
        if (a[0] < b[0]) return false;
        if (a[1] > b[1]) return true;
        if (a[1] < b[1]) return false;
        if (a[2] > b[2]) return true;
        if (a[2] < b[2]) return false;
        return true;
    },
    enableAlerts: function () {
        deployJava.browserName = null;
        deployJava.debug = true;
    },
    writePluginTag: function () {
        var browser = deployJava.getBrowser();
        if (browser == 'MSIE') {
            document.write('<' + 'object classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-DEC7-0000-0000-ABCDEFFEDCBA" ' + 'id="deployJavaPlugin" width="0" height="0">' + '<' + '/' + 'object' + '>');
        } else if (browser == 'Netscape Family' && deployJava.allowPlugin()) {
            deployJava.writeEmbedTag();
        }
    },
    refresh: function () {
        navigator.plugins.refresh(false);
        var browser = deployJava.getBrowser();
        if (browser == 'Netscape Family' && deployJava.allowPlugin()) {
            var plugin = document.getElementById('deployJavaPlugin');
            if (plugin == null) {
                deployJava.writeEmbedTag();
            }
        }
    },
    writeEmbedTag: function () {
        var written = false;
        if (navigator.mimeTypes != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < navigator.mimeTypes.length; i++) {
                if (navigator.mimeTypes[i].type == deployJava.mimeType) {
                    if (navigator.mimeTypes[i].enabledPlugin) {
                        document.write('<' + 'embed id="deployJavaPlugin" type="' + deployJava.mimeType + '" hidden="true" />');
                        written = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!written) for (var i = 0; i < navigator.mimeTypes.length; i++) {
                if (navigator.mimeTypes[i].type == deployJava.oldMimeType) {
                    if (navigator.mimeTypes[i].enabledPlugin) {
                        document.write('<' + 'embed id="deployJavaPlugin" type="' + deployJava.oldMimeType + '" hidden="true" />');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    do_initialize: function () {
        deployJava.writePluginTag();
        if (deployJava.locale == null) {
            var loc = null;
            if (loc == null) try {
                loc = navigator.userLanguage;
            } catch (err) {}
            if (loc == null) try {
                loc = navigator.systemLanguage;
            } catch (err) {}
            if (loc == null) try {
                loc = navigator.language;
            } catch (err) {}
            if (loc != null) {
                loc.replace("-", "_")
                deployJava.locale = loc;
            }
        }
    }
};
deployJava.do_initialize();
```

But I've read regarding this code:

> ...if you have both a Sun JRE and
>   MSJVM installed, the toolkit will
>   report the Sun JRE version even if
>   it's disabled and the browser will
>   actually run MSJVM...

The second problem with that code is that it retrieves a list of the installed JREs, and I only care about the one that will open the Applet I need to deploy inside the browser.

Does someone knows a pure js method to get the version of Java that would run in the browser if I try load an Applet?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440160/detect-version-of-java-using-javascript

Comment: I am posting the same code from the answer of that question and asked a question taking in count that code, not sure if duplicate, maybe related.

Comment: They provide "plain text" version here http://java.com/js/deployJava.txt