# JRE Bit version in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, angular

I need to check the JRE version installed in the client system using javascript. I tried the following code:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
     var versions = deployJava.getJREs();
     alert(versions);
</script>
```

But it was not working for me. It resulted in empty array [].

Is there any other possible solutions for this. Solutions in Angular 6 or Nodejs is also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that it's installed *and enabled* in the tested browser? / Are you using a browser? Nodejs is server-side, not client-side.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440160/detect-version-of-java-using-javascript